# Angular 2 - making an URL

Tags: angular, url, stringbuilder

I'm looking for a way to build an url using variables in my component. I just want it to be dynamic.

Example: "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=skijumper.name"

So if my variable skijumper.name = "Ahonen"

= > this is what I want to achieve : https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Ahonen

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   var url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+skijumper.name;
```

**Edit**

ECMAscript6 :

```
let url = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${skijumper.name}`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let name = "Ahonen";
let urlYoutube = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${name}`;
```